# How to avoid concurrent access of controller method with the same session in java spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, concurrency

I would like to know how to make sure that some method in a service is accessed only once at a time per session.

I'll illustrate by a small example:

Assume we have a user in a state A (user.state = A). This user sends a HTTP GET request to our java spring controller to get a page, say /hello. Based on his status, he will be sent to either A or B. Before that, we will change his status to B (see code below).

Now, assume again that the call dao.doSomething(); takes a lot of time. If the user sends another GET (by refreshing his browser for instance), he will call the exact same method dao.doSomething(), resulting in 2 calls.

**How can you avoid that?**

**What happens if you sends 2 HTTP GETs at the same time?**

**How can you have something consistent in your controller/service/model/database?**

Note 1: here we don't issue the 2 HTTP GETs from different browser. We just make them at the same time on the same browser (I'm aware of the max concurrent session solution, but this does not solve my problem.).

Note 2: the solution should not block concurrent accesses of the controller for different users.

I've read a bit about transaction on service, but I'm not sure if this is the solution. I've also read a bit on concurrency, but I still don't understand how to use it here.

I would greatly appreciate your help! Thanks!

code example:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {    

    @RequestMapping(value='/hello')
    public String viewHelloPage() {

        // we get the user from a session attribute
        if (user.getState() = A) {
            user.setStatus(B);
            return "pageA";
        }

        return "pageB";
    }


@Service
public class UserService {
    Dao dao;

    @Override
    public void setStatus(User user) {
        dao.doSomething();
        user.setStatus(B);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I wouldn't recommend it (as it basically blocks all other calls from the same user to). On most `HandlerAdapter` implementations you can set the property `synchronizeOnSession` by default this is `false` allowing for concurrent requests to come from the same client. When you set this property to `true` requests will be queued for that client.

How to set it depends on your configuration of the `HandlerAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

If `dao.doSomething()` is doing work that you only want to happen once, you should use an idempotent method like PUT or DELETE.  There's no law forcing you to use the correct method, but worst-case it's a self-documenting way to tell the world about how your API should be used.  If that isn't enough for you, most browsers will try to help you out based on the type of request.  For instance, the browser will often use caching to avoid multiple GETs.

It seems like what you really want to know is how to enforce idempotency.  This is very application-specific.  One general approach is to generate and store a pseudo-unique id on the server side for the client to attach to their request.  This way, any request with the same id after the first can be safely ignored.  Obviously old ids should be evicted intelligently.

As I said, the solution is often application-specific.  In your case above, it looks like you're trying to switch between 2 states, and your implementation is a server-side toggle.  You can utilize the client to ensure that multiple requests will not be a problem.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/hello", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
public String test(@RequestParam("state") String state) {
    dao.setState(user, state)
    switch (state) {
        case "A":
            return "B";
        case "B":
            return "A";
        default:
            return "error";
    }
}
```

Comment: See my edits.  If you are modifying state, you should not be using GET.  If you want it to be idempotent, use PUT.  If not, then POST.  If you're trying to enforce idempotency, then that's a separate issue.

Comment: thanks for your update. My question took the GET request as an example, but it applies also for POST. With a POST, you end up with the same problem....

Comment: @laoheike, is this more what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

> how to make sure that some method in a service is accessed only once
>   at a time per session.

Try to Lock on session object in your controller before calling service method

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to configure and use AOP, then the following might help you

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class NonConcurrentAspect implements HttpSessionListener{

    private Map<HttpSession, Map<Method, Object>> mutexes = new ConcurrentHashMap<HttpSession, Map<Method, Object>>();

    @Around(value = "@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
    public Object handle(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint methodPjp = (MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint) pjp;
        Method method = ((MethodSignature) methodPjp.getSignature()).getMethod();
        ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        HttpServletRequest request = requestAttributes.getRequest();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        Object mutex = getMutex(session, method);
        synchronized (mutex) {
            return pjp.proceed();
        }
    }

    private Object getMutex(HttpSession session, Method method) {
        Map<Method, Object> sessionMutexes = mutexes.get(session);
        Object mutex = new Object();
        Object existingMutex = sessionMutexes.putIfAbsent(method, mutex);
        return existingMutex == null ? mutex : existingMutex;
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        mutexes.put(se.getSession(), new ConcurrentHashMap<Method, Object>());
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        mutexes.remove(se.getSession());
    }

}
```

It synchronizes on a per-session per-method mutex. One restriction is that the methods so advised should not call each other (which is hardly a case, unless you violate MVC design pattern severely), otherwise you may face deadlocks.

This would handle all the methods tagged with `@RequestMapping`, but if you want just few methods be guarded against concurrent execution, 
then, as one of the possible solutions, you could introduce your own annotation, e.g.

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface NonConcurrent {
}
```

tag the specific methods with this annotation, and replace `@RequestMapping` in `@Around` annotation in the above aspect class with your own.

In highly contended environment you may think of more advanced solution than intrinsic locks.

I would, however, advise against using `HandlerAdapter`'s `synchronizeOnSession` option, not only because it synchronizes all the invocations on the same mutex, but, which is less obvious, the synchronization on publicly available mutex is potentially dangerous.